# BreakOut Detection Python/R Pkg Installation

Tags: python, breakout

I have been trying to install the BreakOut Detetction pkg in a **Windows enviornment**.

Following is the pkg I am talking about, https://github.com/roland-hochmuth/BreakoutDetection

I was able to get swig on my machine by following the directions@ http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Windows.html

The pkg details 3 steps to install:

```
swig -python -c++ breakout_detection.i 
python setup.py build_ext -I../src build 
sudo python setup.py build_ext -I../src install
```

I somehow got the first step to work. 
The second step gives a lot of compilation errors.

I was wondering if anyone has tried compiling this pkg.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue. i dont know what the deal is, but if you clone from https://github.com/mysl/BreakoutDetection which is a fork off of the roland hochmuth version, the installation commands work (i had to move into the python subfolder before running the commands).

hope it helps